# How to ignore empty directories when using `rm` with wildcards for multiple directories in zsh?

Tags: zsh, rm

When I try to delete all files from two or more subdirectories in `zsh`, and a directory is already empty, the following directories are ignored, and files remain.

Example:

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ mkdir dir2
$ touch dir2/blah

# avoid the zsh safety prompt; this may not be necessary for this
# example, just for ease of use here
$ setopt rm_star_silent
$ rm -r dir1/* dir2/*
zsh: no matches found: dir1/*
$ ls dir2
blah
```

In bash, the already empty directory does not stop `rm` from proceeding to `dir2`, and `dir2/blah` is removed.

What is this `zsh` feature, and is there a way to let `rm` behave like in `bash`?

Comment: Related: [Why is nullglob not default?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `bash`, `zsh` by default reports an error in case a filename generation pattern has no matches. This behavior can be changed globally or on a per-pattern basis.

To prevent error messages from non-matching pattern globally, you can set either of the options `NULL_GLOB` or `CSH_NULL_GLOB`:

- ```
  setopt nullglob
  ```

  If a pattern has no matches it will be removed from the argument list. No error message will be printed. In your example

  ```
  rm dir1/* dir2/*
  ```

  would be just expanded to

  ```
  rm dir2/blah
  ```
- ```
  setopt cshnullglob
  ```

  Also removes non-matching patterns and does not print an error message, unless none of the patterns have a match.

To prevent error messages for single patterns, you can use the glob qualifier `N`, which behaves as if the `NULL_GLOB` option was activated for this pattern:

```
rm dir1/*(N) dir2/*(N)
```

This also would be expanded to

```
rm dir2/blah
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to make it a single glob that matches files in both directories.

```
rm (dir1|dir2)/*
```

That way, the command is still not run if no file is found.

Note however that `dir1`/`dir2` can't contain `/`.

In those cases, you could do instead:

```
files=(foo/bar/*(N) bar/baz/*(N))
if ((#files)); then
  rm $files
else
  echo >&2 No matching file
fi
```

Or use `cshnullglob` to get the csh or pre-Bourne sh behaviour. That's still better than reverting to the bogus (IMO) behaviour of `bash` (where non-matching globs are passed asis to the command) which you can do with:

```
set +o nomatch
```

Answer (score -2):

A good explanation can be found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/584249/using-wildcards-in-commands-with-zsh

The gist  is:

```
By default, ZSH will generate the filenames and throw an error before executing the command if it founds no matches.
```

Your empty directory is going to generate no matches and thus an error.
As the answer indicates, you can either:

1. Enclose the argument in quotes (e.g. `rm -r "dir1/*" "dir2/*"`) OR
2. Setting `unsetopt nomatch` in your `.zshrc` file OR
3. Prefacing you can command with the `noglob` environment variable (e.g. `noglob rm -r dir1/* dir2/*`)

Comment: This is not the same use case as in the linked question. As such points 1. and 3. of your answer will not work at all. And although 2. will remove the file, it will still print an error message and exit with an error code.